# Указать версию библиотеки MFC при компиляции

Tags: c++, mfc

Пишу дополнение для приложения, которое установлено на неподдерживаемой более версии Windows, и изменить какое-либо ПО не представляеться возможным.
В системе установлен Visual C++ redistributable 2008. т.е. 90 версию.
Я собираю все на VS2015 и могу при сборке выбирать 120 и 140 версии MFC, соответственно. 
В системе у меня установлен msvc++ redist 2008, но указать эту версию я при компиляции не могу, т.к. Visual studio не предлагает этот вариант.
Как в параметрах компиляции указать специфичную версию библиотек, для которых я хочу собрать бинарник, т.к. линковать статично я не хочу.